# Wordpress: wpdb prepare with conditional variable

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, prepared-statement

I currently have a table. If the user searches for something, I would like the query to return the filtered results. If the user doesn't search for something, it should return all results. I'm not too sure how to do this with wpdb prepare.

```
if($search_query!=="all") {
    $search_query = '%' . $search_query . '%';
    $where = 'WHERE column_name LIKE %s';   
}

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name ".$where." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $search_query,$current_page,$rows_per_page));
```

Right now nothing returns when the search field is empty because the query is erroring out because it's throwing the parametrization off and passing $search_query to the %d beside LIMIT. Is it possible to make this variable conditional? Is there a way to do this without an IF statement ?

Comment: Try putting the call to `get_results` inside the if - you can put a second call in an `else`, and each one gets passed the parameters it requires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do the prepare in the "If" statement? You can then do the other prepare (without the where clause) in the "Else" and just use the get_results on the proper prepared query?

```
if($search_query!=="all") {
    $search_query = '%' . $search_query . '%';
    $where = 'WHERE column_name LIKE %s'; 
    $prepared = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name ".$where." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $search_query, $current_page, $rows_per_page)  ;
} else {
    $prepared = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $current_page, $rows_per_page);
}
$results = $wpdb->get_results($prepared);
```

Comment: Right, so that will be my last resort. I'm going to have a lot more optional variables, so it would be a lot easier to manage the sql statement if I have just one query. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of what else you'll be having? Is it more variables in the "where" clause?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So it will end up looking something like: WHERE name LIKE %s OR date LIKE %s OR location LIKE %s OR phone LIKE %s......

Comment: So you would want to pass in everything with a default of "LIKE %%", similar to @Nikos suggestion and set the variable to an actual string only if it is passed.  It is similar to just writing "if 1==1" instead of passing a blank variable which would error out

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can pass an array to `prepare`, as well as a list of variables, according [to the WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

That means that you could do something like this:

```
$where = "";

$parameters = array($search_query,$current_page,$rows_per_page);

if($search_query!=="all") {
    array_push($parameters, '%' . $search_query . '%');
    $where = 'WHERE column_name LIKE %s';   
}

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name ".$where." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $parameters));
```

Your WHERE clause will be empty if there's no data, so concatenating it into your query won't cause issues.

Comment: Nice solution. I never realized you could also pass an array

Comment: Me either, actually - it's always good when you think 'It'd be great if you could do...', and look it up in the documentation to find that the developers had anticipated you.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the `like` parameter yourself and add it as a where clause if needed like this:

```
function like($str)
{
    global $wpdb;
    return "'" . '%' . esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($str)) . '%' . "'";
}

if($search_query!=="all") {
    $where = 'WHERE column_name LIKE ' . like($search_query);   
}
```

and remove the `search_query` param from the `prepared` statement